# Making apply() function's code applicable to 2GB

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have approximately 2GB of data and I want to create some new columns based on analyzing the values of other columns. In particular I have the following code that works fine on a smaller data set, but fails all the time when applied to 2G (memory error).

Is it possible to replace this code by some other one that would be more efficient and would require less RAM?

```
def calculate(row):
    features = [111,222,333,444,555] 
    if row['C_1'] in features:
        return 1
    if row['C_2'] in features:
        return 1
    if row['C_3'] in features:
        return 1
    if row['C_4'] in features:
        return 1
    if row['C_5'] in features:
        return 1
    return 0
result["NEW_COL"] = result.apply (lambda row: calculate(row),axis=1)
```

Comment: Instead of writing code that will use less RAM on the entire file, why not read in your data in [chunks so you don't exceed the memory limit](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/io.html#iterating-through-files-chunk-by-chunk)?

Comment: Crashing at the limit of 2G sounds like a 32 bits python is used. Try a 64 bits version if you really need to have all data in memory at once.  But it's usually better to process it in chunks as mentioned here

Comment: Should it be like this? `reader = pd.read_table('tmp.sv', sep='|', chunksize=4)

for chunk in reader:  chunk["NEW_COL"] = chunk.apply (lambda row: calculate(row),axis=1)` How can then I merge everything into a new `result`?

Comment: You do still have to adjust for your problem, but your `result` should now be in `chunk`. Why not just try it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than processing in parts, something like the following may be more efficient:

```
features = (111, 222, 333, 444, 555)
t = result.isin(features)
result['NEW_COL'] = t['C_1'] | t['C_2'] | t['C_3'] | t['C_4'] | t['C_5']
```